# Java - convert String (EEST included) into date

Tags: java, string

I'm having this kind of String:

```
Wed Oct 27 00:00:00 EEST 2010
```

and I want to parse this into type Date.

I've tried with

```
DateTimeFormat fmt = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
```

but it doesn't work.

Need help in getting this fixed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using simple date format. Here is an example.. [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) java docs...

```
String dt = "Wed Oct 27 00:00:00 EEST 2010";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
Date date = format.parse(dt);
System.out.println("date = " + date);
```

Comment: Don't forget that SimpleDateFormat is unsynchronized so the parsing must be done in a synchronized block.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys,

I need to use DateTimeFormat because with SimpleDateFormat it doesn't work because I'm using GWT.

I'm running my project with GWT plugin from IntellijIdea and there I have this 2 errors if I'm using SimpleDateFormat:

```
[ERROR] Line 164: SimpleDateFormat cannot be resolved to a type
[ERROR] Line 167: ParseException cannot be resolved to a type
```