# Creating Date from string (EEST format problem)

Tags: java, android

I have problem converting from string to date.

The first one i Ok:

```
    Date d = new Date("Thu Jun 02 00:00:00 GMT+00:00 2011");
```

this one is fali(invalid argument):

```
    Date d1 = new Date("Mon Jun 06 00:00:00 EEST 2011");
```

Any suggestion? I need universal solution that will work with any format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the next Q&A might solve your problem:
[Java - convert String (EEST included) into date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977925/java-convert-string-eest-included-into-date)

In short: you cannot use Date, but must use SimpleDateFormat.